# Can I safely delete my /Library/Keychains/System.keychain file?

Tags: macos, security, keychain

I'd like to clear all memory of passwords, certificates, etc., from my MacBook and start over.
It seems like deleting the `/Library/Keychains/System.keychain` file and restarting is the simplest way to achieve this.
Is it safe to do this?

I'd also like to delete: `/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain`

Is that safe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [SU] or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com). Stack Overflow is for questions related to programming.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the mis-post. I've reposted to SuperUser. So, go ahead and close this.